# Firebase query download the whole database. Why?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I try to download and show only specific data from the Realtime Database. I have the following code:

```
getUserPlatformIos() {
    this.dataRef = this.afDatabase.list('data/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('meta/platform').equalTo('ios'));
      this.data = this.dataRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      });
      return this.data;
  }
```

**My firebase database structure**
[image]

**Firebase rules**
[image]

Why firebase does download the whole database if I query before? This causes very long loading times and a lot of downloaded data....

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with the actual rules and JSON as text. You can easily get the JSON by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON and rules as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual rules and data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indexes need to be defined at the place where you the query. Since you run the query on `data/users`, that's where you need to define your index:

```
"users": {
  ".indexOn": "meta/platform"
}
```

This defines an index on `users`, which has the value of the `meta/platform` property of each user.

Note that the log output of your app should be showing an error message with precisely this information. I highly recommend checking log output whenever something doesn't work the way you expect it to work.

Comment: Perfect!! That does work! Many thanks! :) I´ve not getting error messages in the browser console...